MAP Sort based on Keys
How can we sort a MAP based on Keys in Aws Athena SQL
select map_from_entries(array_agg(row(a,b)))
from
(
 SELECT a, b
FROM unnest(map(ARRAY['z', 'a', 'b', 'c'], ARRAY[1, 2, 3, 4])) AS t(a, b)
order by a desc
)

Would like to get {a=2, b=3, c=4, z=1}  But I am getting {a=2, b=3, z=1, c=4}
Trino doesnt have function map_top_n_keys as in Presto.. Thanks

Hi Ramesh please provide the code you used as an example to discuss about and help you.

@MarianoSchmands Please see another code snippet below
 WITH my_map_data AS (
    SELECT map(ARRAY['2023Q1', '2024Q1', '2022Q4', '2021Q3'], ARRAY[2, 3, 1, 4]) AS my_map
)
SELECT my_map from my_map_data;

Here we have a MAP created with Year||Quarter and corresponding values, we need the map to be created in a sorted order of Year||Quater.
The above query result in AWS Athena using Trino is
{2023Q1=2, 2021Q3=4, 2024Q1=3, 2022Q4=1}.
Hope that helps. Thanks

Maps/dictionaries are unordered structures (though there are special cases like SortedMap in Java or SortedDictionary in C# but Trino/Presto do not expose such datastructure). The closest you can do is to sort an array of rows created from a map:
-- sample data
with dataset(m) as (
    values ( map(ARRAY['z', 'a', 'b', 'c'], ARRAY[1, 2, 3, 4]) )
)

-- query
select array_sort(map_entries(m), (l, r) -> if(l[1] > r[1], 1, -1)) sorted_arr,
       map_from_entries(array_sort(map_entries(m), (l, r) -> if(l[1] > r[1], 1, -1))) sorted_arr_to_map
from dataset;

Output:



sorted_arr
sorted_arr_to_map




[{a, 2}, {b, 3}, {c, 4}, {z, 1}]
{a=2, b=3, z=1, c=4}




Trino doesn't have function map_top_n_keys as in Presto

And this one is easily simulated with map and array functions:
-- query
select slice(array_sort(map_keys(m)), 1, 3)
from dataset;

Output:
   _col0
-----------
 [a, b, c]

